# No SSIDB folder under Integration Services Catalogue

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms

We have some jobs that are using SSIS packages but I cannot find SSIDB under Integration Services Catalogue. How can I view all the SSIS projects. Is there any other place I can find packages.Please see Images:

[image]

Comment: Are you actually using the SSISDB deployment model? Do you have an SSISDB database on the instance?

Comment: new to SSIS. I want to see where they are deployed. Also want a production copy of the projects. Not sure where to find SSISDB. But under databses its not.

Comment: +1 @Larnu -- you can check by right clicking on the `Integration Services Catalog` folder.  If ssisdb is installed `Create Catalog` should be greyed out, which would suggest you have a permissions issue.  If it is not installed, packages could be stored on file system or msdb.  Check any sql agent job that calls a package to see how it is configured.

Comment: In sql agent job it says source is file system. If I want to make changes to package what steps I need to follow?

Comment: You would need to open that package in Visual Studio then, @vicky , though (hopefully) you actually have a project in a Version Control repository that you should be opening, editting, and then deploying the amended package to the File System. Also, however, I do personally suggest switch to the SSISDB deployment; it's a much better system than the old File System and MSDB deployment methods.

Comment: Agree with @Larnu.  First check if anyone knows if the packages are in source control.  If not, copy the files from the filesystem into a new SSIS visual studio project and then check that into source control.  Then edit and paste them over top of files in the file system to update them.  SSISDB would be something that you can migrate to over time.